# What does the written and unwritten international law say about an eventual shutdown of Zaporizhzhia Nuclear Power Plant?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine

Russian invasion of Ukraine in 2022.

After the Russian forces [occupied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine#Southern_front) Zaporizhzhia Nuclear Power Plant there have been a lot of discussions about the risk of radiation leak, but not about the main objective. It is obvious that Russia goal is to cut off the electricity supply, not to spread radiations since they would affect an area that they want to occupy.

What I don't understand are the legal implications because the international law on such issues is a mix of written agreements and unwritten conventions. Cutting off the electricity to industrial areas is an obvious military target. But cutting off electricity to densely populated cities is something more ambiguous.

So I would like to know if the plant is still working or if the electricity has been already cut off and I would like to know the legal implications of cutting off the electricity to the civilian population.

Comment: Can we try to find a title which doesn't use the word "implications"? That is a really vague word which doesn't make clear what kind of answers you actually expect. Especially if combined with "unwritten".

Comment: @Philipp I was vague because the international law is mostly unwritten conventions, I'll try and rephrase it.

Comment: I also think we should leave the specific incident of the Zaporizhzhia plant out of the title and ask for the general case instead. That would make the question more useful for the future as a potential dupe target if the same question arises for a different power plant in a different conflict.

Comment: @Philipp Actually I am asking also if they actually cut off the electricity. That plant is the biggest in Ukraine and a lot of people depend on its supply.

Comment: Is that really a question about politics and political processes, though? Do we really need a question to confirm or deny every single strategic development in this war?

Comment: Real life is so complex that often you cannot generalise. Did you see in the US movies how often lawyers rely on legal precedents? Specific cases in law and politics sometimes matter.

Comment: @Philipp "Do we really need a question to confirm or deny every single strategic development in this war?" We should try to make these questions more general like asking not about this war but in general. I think this question almost does it. It seems to ask: "What does international law say about cutting electricity off?".

Comment: "So I would like to know if the plant is still working or if the electricity has been already cut off"  This is no political question. Please just search in the news. "I would like to know the legal implications of cutting off the electricity to the civilian population." Not sure this is really that useful to know. To you think that somebody might sue Russia with any consequences for Russia? I think that this is extremely unlikely so this part of the question might not be very interesting.

Comment: From what I recall NATO attacked some Serbian power plants with graphite-based  denial weapons. https://www.theguardian.com/world/1999/may/04/martinwalker1 also a wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite_bomb

Comment: FluidCode, Could you please modify the body or the title so that both are in alignment? In the body you are asking about the legality of cutting off electricity to a civilian population. In the title you are asking about shutting down a nuclear reactor. While the _purpose_ of shutting down the reactor may be cutting off electricity, there rules, regulations and laws regarding the use and startup/shutdown of a nuclear reactor beyond what the reactor is powering. Do you really want to know the laws about shutting down the reactor, about cutting off power, or both (may be too broad)?